# Interaction between Ruby App and Other App using GET and POST request

Tags: ruby, http-post

I have two Apps, one in Ruby and other one in PHP (Assume, there is a different team developing this app).

Ideally what happens is; Other App sends request to Ruby App with some parameters, I want to store this Parameters in database on Ruby App's side. Then Ruby App picks up this parameters does some processing and saves data back in Database and again.

Now I want to send request to Other App with new parameters. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You write the Ruby app so it is run from a web server (I believe [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is still a popular way to do that in Ruby land) to get the requests, and then use an HTTP library (Google finds [NET:HTTPSession](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)) to make the requests back to the other service.

Comment: I am running my Ruby App from Web Server. As of now it is command-line App. I have to put it on one of our servers. Do I really need Rails in this (I tried using rails but it makes app heavy). Can't I just have core Ruby engine and then make request to that engine.

Comment: You don't need Rails, Rails just does a lot of the work involved in interfacing with HTTP for you. If you want to start with nothing but the basic ruby binary, then you will need to write a web server in Ruby (which is a lot of effort which you can avoid). There are various stages between the two extremes that you might also go for.